# Why canPerformAction get called again when action of menuItem is called?

Tags: ios, swift

Below is my code, I found when click menu "pasteAndGo", two log strings are printed: 1. paste and go show 2.paste and go clicked. My requirement is when the menu is shown, log "paste and go show" is shown. When it is clicked, log "paste and go clicked" is shown.

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

      private func Init() {
          let menuController: UIMenuController = UIMenuController.shared
          menuController.isMenuVisible = true
          let pasteAndGoMenuItem: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "pasteAndGo", action: #selector(pasteAndGo(sender:)))

          let myMenuItems: NSArray = [pasteAndGoMenuItem]
          menuController.menuItems = myMenuItems as? [UIMenuItem]
      }

      @objc private func pasteAndGo(sender: UIMenuItem) {
          Print("paste and go clicked")
      }

      override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
          let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general

          if action == #selector(pasteAndGo) {
              if pasteboard.url != nil {
              Print("paste and go show")
                  return true
          } else {
              return false
          }
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as implemented:

- In the instant you press your *pasteAndGo* menu item, the UIKit framework calls `canPerformAction` to ask whether it is allowed to execute the action or not. Here, you print "paste and go show"
- Since you return `true`, your action `pasteAndGo(sender:)` is executed and prints "paste and go clicked"

To react on the menu item being shown, you'll have to register to the notification center with the `UIMenuController.willShowMenuNotification`, like this:

```
// create a property 
var token: NSObjectProtocol?

// then add observer  
self.token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIMenuController.willShowMenuNotification, object: nil, queue: .main)
    { _ in
        print ("paste and go show")
    }
```

and don't forget to unsubscribe (`NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver`) once your viewcontroller gets dismissed.

```
if let t = self.token {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(t)
}
```

---

Update

You could also do so (without properties) in `Init`

```
// in Init
var token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIMenuController.willShowMenuNotification, object: nil, queue: .main)
    { _ in
        print ("paste and go show")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token)
    }
```

Comment: I only want to print "paste and go show" when it is shown, not print it when UIMenuControllerWillShowMenu.

Comment: This is what happens when the notification center calls "UIMenuControllerWillShowMenu"

Comment: You do not post the notification, the _UIKit framework_ will post it (by means of the Notification Center) when it shows the menu. You just add a callback (e.g. a closure, or a `func`) to be called. There are also other notifications being posted in the context of `UIMenu`, just check the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller

Comment: I just want to print "paste and go show" when the UIMenuController includes the menuItem I included not UIMenuController shown.

Comment: Then you add the notification observer only when your menu is being displayed (in `Init`) and remove it directly in the closure, see my edits.

Comment: "pasteAndGo" is a customized menuItem which isn't included in UIMenuController. only the text in UIPasteBorad is a url, "pasteAndgo" will shown in UIMenuController, otherwise, there is no "pasteAndGo" menuItem. "paste and go show" is only when menuItem is included in the UIMenuController.

Comment: Then, you add the notification in `canPerformAction`.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. The code just works. When the menu item is shown, it displays "paste and go show". Btw, when do you call `Init`?